# Is that a faster way to convert hierarchy list to a list based on how many path it cloud have?

Tags: c#, hierarchy

I couldn't know what the proper naming for this question.

Definition is simple, that's a hierarchy list(I also able generate flattened list)

```
Simply show hierarchy view
hierarchy I able to get
1
-->2
-->3
   -->4
   -->5
-->6

flattened list I able to get
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

result I wanted is

```
[
  [1,2],
  [1,3,4],
  [1,3,5],
  [1,6],
]
```

sample class I have

```
public class MemberNetworkViewModel
{
    public int MemberGenerationNumber { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId{ get; set; }
    public List<MemberNetworkViewModel> children { get; set; }
}
```

I could do the hardest way around which is try to get who is the last node in this hierarchy list, then `foeeach` them and get their parent one by one. But I think there will be a better way, any ideas ?

**Current Solution (bypass, I know is messy, seeking help for shorter by linq maybe?)**

```
    public List<List<MemberNetworkViewModel>> GetAllPossibleNetworkTreePath(
        List<MemberNetworkViewModel> flatternMemberNetworkViewModel)
    {
        var possibleTreePaths = new List<List<MemberNetworkViewModel>>();

        var lastNodes =
            flatternMemberNetworkViewModel.Where(
                x => flatternMemberNetworkViewModel.All(y => y.ParentId!= x.MemberId));

        foreach (var lastNode in lastNodes)
        {
            var memberNetworkViewModels = new List<MemberNetworkViewModel>();
            memberNetworkViewModels.Add(lastNode);
            for (int index = 0; index < lastNode.MemberGenerationNumber; index++)
            {
                var parent =
                    flatternMemberNetworkViewModel.FirstOrDefault(
                        x => x.MemberId == memberNetworkViewModels.Last().ParentId);
                memberNetworkViewModels.Add(parent);
            }
            memberNetworkViewModels = (from x in memberNetworkViewModels
                orderby x.MemberGenerationNumber
                select x).ToList();

            possibleTreePaths.Add(memberNetworkViewModels);
        }

        return possibleTreePaths;
    }
```

Comment: Seems convoluted .. I'd use a Tree instead

Comment: Then your sub-lists are just the path from root to leaf, which can be obtained easily if you need them

Comment: @CedricDruck because I need do some checking according to tree path. I know sound curious but that's requested by client. So I think my own suggestion is the better way ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you show the source list in code and the desired list also in code?

Comment: why `1,2,3,4` and NOT `1,3,4` ??? or is that typo

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary sorry, that is typo

Comment: @ZoharPeled I edited and provide current solution, please check maybe it let you know what I trying to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your source data in a tree it becomes much easier.

It looks like you do already have a tree, held in the form of a list. You just need to know the element in the list which represents the root, and use that as the starting point to traverse the tree.

You can write a general-purpose method to traverse the tree and output the routes to all the leaves like so:

```
public static void Flatten<T, U>(T root, Func<T, U> select, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, Action<List<U>> output)
{
    List<U> pathSoFar = new List<U>();
    flatten(pathSoFar, root, select, children, output);
}

static void flatten<T, U>(List<U> pathSoFar, T root, Func<T, U> select, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, Action<List<U>> output)
{
    pathSoFar.Add(select(root));
    bool any = false;
    var offspring = children(root);

    if (offspring != null)
    {
        foreach (var child in offspring)
        {
            any = true;
            flatten(pathSoFar, child, select, children, output);
        }
    }

    if (!any)
        output(pathSoFar.ToList());

    pathSoFar.RemoveAt(pathSoFar.Count-1);
}
```

The Func that you pass as the `output` parameter will be called once for each path to a leaf.

A complete compilable console app which duplicates your input is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Node
    {
        public int ID;
        public List<Node> Children;
    }

    public class MemberNetworkViewModel
    {
        public int MemberGenerationNumber { get; set; }
        public int MemberId { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public List<MemberNetworkViewModel> children { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node root =
                new Node {ID = 1, Children = new List<Node>{
                    new Node {ID = 2 },
                    new Node {ID = 3, Children = new List<Node>{
                        new Node {ID = 4},
                        new Node {ID = 5}}},
                    new Node {ID = 6}
                }};

            Flatten(
                root, 
                node => node.ID,
                node => node.Children,
                path => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", path)));
        }

        public static void Flatten<T, U>(T root, Func<T, U> select, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, Action<List<U>> output)
        {
            List<U> pathSoFar = new List<U>();
            flatten(pathSoFar, root, select, children, output);
        }

        static void flatten<T, U>(List<U> pathSoFar, T root, Func<T, U> select, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children, Action<List<U>> output)
        {
            pathSoFar.Add(select(root));
            bool any = false;
            var offspring = children(root);

            if (offspring != null)
            {
                foreach (var child in offspring)
                {
                    any = true;
                    flatten(pathSoFar, child, select, children, output);
                }
            }

            if (!any)
                output(pathSoFar.ToList());

            pathSoFar.RemoveAt(pathSoFar.Count-1);
        }
    }
}
```

For your `MemberNetworkViewModel` class you would call it like so:

```
MemberNetworkViewModel root = whatever;

Flatten(
    root,
    node => node.MemberId,
    node => node.children,
    path => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", path)));
```

Comment: Looks very good, but why the `pathSoFar.ToList()` ? That's a lot of list (and underlying array) copying going on that can be easily avoided by removing the element you added in the recursion.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That's true; I was just going for simplicity. I've amended the code to prevent making so many copies - but note that I still make a copy for each returned list (which has to be done otherwise the returned list would keep changing during iteration!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson this is very surprising ! Looks like I gonna study more on `Func, Action and generic`